# How to add an article to a template

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I'm a noob, just on day 3 of learning how to use Joomla.  I am working with the *shaper Helix II* template; I have my logo and menu up and working, but can't figure out how to get an article with an image into the *main body* of the template.  This is the image of the template (don't know any other way of describing it):
[image]

and this is the image of the web page so far:
[image]

I can't figure out how to get the article into the Main Body...  I've watched tutorials, read books and still can't figure it out.  What I really need is a *good* document (like a cookbook) that shows step by step how to accomplish stuff like this.  Can someone please help me?  I  would really appreciate it.  SD

Comment: I don't know helix, but is usually called "component". Then when you make a menu item and select a single article and the article you want, the component will be that article, as the menu item defines the component in the layout. If you want the article **in addition** to the component, use a module. Make a module position and put a Custom HTML module with the text of the article in it. Or use a module extension that lets you directly load an article.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear; HOW do I connect a *category* (not a component) to a specific spot on the template?

Comment: Comment was over length, so I copy pasted it to an answer. Not sure if it answers **the question** as I actually wrote it to answer your **comment**, but I hope it is useful anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create an article as

content -> Article Manager -> Add new Article.

You will have to use any menu item for it to be displayed.

Comment: Please see comment above to Ville's comment.

Comment: I just found out that menu's make the page... thanks for your time.

Comment: for your category part - There are some modules that would list your categories at a specific " position " of the template.

- positions are pre-defined positions in the layout of the template where you can put specific modules as per your requirements and then there are modules that can help you get your stuff done.You will have to look for these extensions in extensions.joomla.org

Answer (score 3):

I *think* I kind of get what you mean. **If** so, then you are kind of misunderstanding how Joomla! and templates work, which is why tutorials are hard to get.

In Joomla! content such as articles and appearance are managed separately. So you don't really add content directly to templates, you add positions, which you then add the content from elsewhere. There are two types of positions, **one** component position which shows whatever component is defined for a specific menu item and a variable number of module positions that show whatever modules have been assigned to those positions. Both types can show articles or even entire categories of articles.